# Compare two different objects with jasmine .toEqual, and one object is empty and the other has a key that is a symbol, why does it say they are equal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

Here is my expect statement

```
const otherObject = { [Symbol('what')]: { key: 'value' } };
expect({}).toEqual(otherObject); // succeeds
```

The expectation is to be for the test to fail.

Why does jasmine report this test a success? I am using jasmine@3.5

Here is the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-platform-rceq0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It currently just won't work using a `Symbol` as key. When `jasmine` is doing the comparison, it tries to get the `keys` of the object, see [jasmine.js#L4551](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/83b336d9d1a22caf58e0985210a623471a2001ef/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L4551), the function used to extract the keys use `Object.keys`, see [jasmine.js#L4587](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/83b336d9d1a22caf58e0985210a623471a2001ef/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L4587).

See the following example

```
const otherObject = { [Symbol('what')]: { key: 'value' } };
console.log(Object.keys(otherObject)); // ouput []
```

So, when `jasmine` run the comparison `expect({}).toEqual(otherObject);` it is comparing if `{}` using deep equality comparison is equal to `{}`, and it is `true`, it is comparing two empty objects, literally.

It won't work either using the following example that should fail, but it passes:

```
const mySymbol = Symbol('what');
const otherObject = { [mySymbol]: { key: 'value' } };
expect(otherObject).toEqual(
  jasmine.objectContaining({ [mySymbol]: { key: 'value2' } })
);
```

So, you can iterate your object using [Object.getOwnPropertySymbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) and write an expectation for each value.

Or, you can open a feature request to the Jasmine team so they consider validating `Symbols` and not only keys.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation with links!